# InterfaceBuilder and UIButton+ImageViewContentMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, interface-builder

I'm trying to add to Interface Builder the `contentMode` property of the `imageView` property of an `UIButton`. I've written the basic stuff but it IB refuses to show the property in a `Button` section (the section itself is there, but it's empty). Here's the code:

## UIButton+ImageContentMode.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (ImageContentMode)

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIViewContentMode imageContentMode;

@end
```

## UIButton+ImageContentMode.m

```
#import "UIButton+ImageContentMode.h"

@implementation UIButton (ImageContentMode)

@dynamic imageContentMode;

- (void) setImageContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode {
    self.imageView.contentMode = contentMode;
}

@end
```

I've already written similar code extending `UIView` and it works fine there, but with `UIButton` it doesn't work. I'm using XCode 8.3.2.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have an property imageContentMode and you are overwriting its setter and does not even assign the given property. That is not a good practice, is there a reason why you need this property? You could just set your contentMode when needed, why use extension? it seems like overkill.

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis this is how it is supposed to work. Category can't add "storage" per se, and I actually don't need/want to, because I only want to set an already existing property,so I'm kinda creating a "proxy" property.